# Extract range of Arabic letters in python

Tags: python, regex, arabic

I have a string of data that has digits, English, and Arabic text, and I want only to extact the Arabic letters. The structure is a little bit difficult,

```
@service:Card Issuance
البريد يوصل 
لي البطاقة ؟
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#CMP_Cards_Lost
@closureReason:لم تعد هناك حاجة إلى البطاقة
@cardchoice:البطاقة 4
@cardchoice:البطاقة 2
2 more...
عادي اطلب البطاقة 
عن طريق البريد
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#FAQ_Request_Card_Delivery
@service:Card Delivery
شلون طريقه تحديث 
البيانات
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#NVG_SS_UpdatingData
@data:البيانات
احتاج احدث 
البيانات
 الشخصية
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#NVG_SS_UpdatingData
@data:البيانات
كيف احدث 
البيانات
```

I tried a few things like:

```
 print (' ' .join(re.findall('[\u0600-\u06FF]+', str(n))))
```

but it doesn't work as I wanted.

The output that I want could be a list, a data frame, or another suitable structure.

```
"البريد يوصل لي البطاقة " , " لم تعد هناك حاجة الى البطاقة" , " شلون طريقة تحديث البيانات" , "احتاج احدث البيانات الشخصية "
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[Note: I neither speak nor read Arabic, so my solution could be incomplete.]

Use `unicodedata` to extract Arabic characters (and others you want to keep).

```
import unicodedata

txt = """@service:Card Issuance
البريد يوصل 
لي البطاقة ؟
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#CMP_Cards_Lost
@closureReason:لم تعد هناك حاجة إلى البطاقة
@cardchoice:البطاقة 4
@cardchoice:البطاقة 2
2 more...
عادي اطلب البطاقة 
عن طريق البريد
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#FAQ_Request_Card_Delivery
@service:Card Delivery
شلون طريقه تحديث 
البيانات
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#NVG_SS_UpdatingData
@data:البيانات
احتاج احدث 
البيانات
 الشخصية
09/21/2022 @ 2:43 PM
Open conversation
#NVG_SS_UpdatingData
@data:البيانات
كيف احدث 
البيانات"""

# Additional characters to keep
keep = " "

origlines = txt.splitlines()
outlines = []
for ln in origlines:
    cleaned = "".join(
        [c for c in ln if "ARABIC" in unicodedata.name(c) or c in keep]
    )
    if cleaned and not cleaned.isspace():
        outlines.append(cleaned.strip())

for oln in outlines:
    print(oln)
```

This produces:

```
البريد يوصل
لي البطاقة ؟
لم تعد هناك حاجة إلى البطاقة
البطاقة
البطاقة
عادي اطلب البطاقة
عن طريق البريد
شلون طريقه تحديث
البيانات
البيانات
احتاج احدث
البيانات
الشخصية
البيانات
كيف احدث
البيانات
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I got this error : NameError: name 'unicodedata' is not defined, how to fix it ?

Comment: @MahaMohammed Did you perhaps forget to import it? The script runs fine on Python 3.9.14.

Comment: @MahaMohammed Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: it works fine now, thanks a lot but its not quite what I want, because I want the whole sentence like "I want to update my account" but now its separated "i want" "to" "update" "my account", do you have any idea how to get it as a sentence ?

Comment: @MahaMohammed One possible approach would be to split the text at the lines containing the dates and times, and then concatenate the lines of Arabic between them.

Comment: @MahaMohammed And keep in mind the disclaimer I put at the top of my answer. It is there for a reason. :-)

Comment: @MahaMohammed It also struck me that some of the lines of Arabic end in a space. That would suggest there is more to come? Would concatenating those lines with the lines below them make sense?

Comment: yes it's a huge data, i don't think concatenating is the right approach here, ill try to take everything between "Open conversation" to "Open conversation" and then extract only the Arabic text using for loop, what do you think ?

Comment: That could work.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex fails to include spaces.

```
print(re.findall('(?!\s)[\s\u0600-\u06FF]+', str(n)))
```

You haven't revealed what `n` is; I'm guessing you can probably take out the `str()` too.

The `(?!\s)` lookahead is a minor tweak to avoid having the match start on a newline or other whitespace.

Demo: https://ideone.com/P7MXEw

Comment: n is the string you see

Comment: I guessed correctly then. But you will want to make sure your question is self-contained. Don't make us guess.

Comment: okay but its not the output I want, its exactly what I did.

Comment: Sorry, I had accidentally removed the crucial `\s` from the code here when editing it; updated now to include it again.